# git svn command; svn binding issue

Tags: perl, git, svn, git-svn, swig

While executing "git svn" init/clone, I am getting following error:

> $ git svn init .
>
> Can't load '/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so' for module SVN::_Core: libsvn_client-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
> at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/SVN/Base.pm line 59
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/SVN/Core.pm line 5.
> Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
> Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Git/SVN.pm line 33.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Git/SVN.pm line 33.
> Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 25.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 25.

following packages are installed:

1. git version 1.8.0
2. SWIG Version 2.0.9
   Compiled with g++ [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
   Configured options: -pcre
3. svn, version 1.6.18 (r1303927)
   compiled Jan 22 2013, 12:39:04
4. perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Appreciate your suggestions in this.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like file:

```
 /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so
```

is missing. It should be a part of your svn package. Most likely your svn compilation went wrong (some missing perl support?).

Anyway, the file _Core.so is a part of:

```
http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/dag/redhat/el4/x86_64/extras/subversion-perl-1.4.4-0.1.el4.rfx.x86_64.html
```

If you are tired of compilation, try to find appropriate rpm package and install it.

Comment: The file is present. See: >ls /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/
_Core.bs  _Core.so

Comment: All the above packages are installed from source.. not rpm. I have compiled and installed using makefile.

Comment: if exists, maybe it is corrupted. try ldd _Core.so .Also check perl module SVN::_Core - does it exists?, libsvn_client-1.so.0 exists and is valid? Definitely the error has to be somewhere in these files/modules. During makfile compilation usually you can switch on/off some modules (some perl support in your case I suppose)

Comment: All files exists but the same error. >perl -MSVN::Core -e 0
>Can't load '/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so' for module SVN::_Core: libsvn_client-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
 at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/SVN/Base.pm line 59
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/SVN/Core.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: Is there any version mismatch problem among svn-perl-swig-git? Also I noticed that under "/usr/lib64/perl5"; I have 3 directories: 5.8.8, site_perl, vendor_perl

Comment: take a look on the error message: it says that module SVN::_Core couldn't load _Core.so and maybe some other problem with libsvn_client-1.so.0. Those files are not in particular directories or there are corrupted. Make sure that they really exist and whether they can be loaded (dependencies linked correctly through ldd command). You dan't have to take care about number of dirs -just look if the files exist in dirs which were written in the error message

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions @xhudik

Everything was installed correctly and present at correct location. The problem was linking library correctly. Just `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` did the trick for me.

Now i just need to keep this env variable permanent. Everything is working now.